# Haskell Regex non capture group

Tags: regex, haskell

I'm using Text.Regex.TDFA on Lazy ByteString for extract some infomation from a file.

I have to extract each byte from this string:

```
 27 FB D9 59 50 56 6C 8A
```

Here is what i've tried (my string begins with space):

```
(\\ ([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))+
```

but i have 2 problems:

- Only last match is returned [[" 27 FB D9 59 50 56 6C 8A"," 8A","8A"]]
- I want to make the outer group non caputing one (like ?: in other engines)

Here is my minimal code:

```
import System.IO ()
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L
import Text.Regex.TDFA


main::IO()
main = do
    let input = L.pack " 27 FB D9 59 50 56 6C 8A"
    let entries = input =~ "(\\ ([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))+" :: [[L.ByteString]]
    print  entries
```

Comment: 1st solved. thanks Brian Stephens :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you attach a multiplier to a capture group, the engine returns only the last match. See [rexegg.com/regex-capture.html#groupnumbers](http://rexegg.com/regex-capture.html#groupnumbers) for a good explanation.

On the first pass, use this regex, similar to what you were already using (using a case-insensitive option):

`^([\dA-F]+) +([\dA-F]+) +(\d+) +([\dA-F]+)(( [\dA-F]{2})+)`

You'll get the following matching groups:

[image]

Use the 5th one as the target of a second pass, to extract each individual byte (using a "global" option):

`([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})`

Then each match will be returned separately.

**Note:** you don't need to escape the spaces, as you had in your original regex.

Comment: I need to capture from this "6000      60B  109743043 0008 27 FB D9 59 50 56 6C 8A " and my full regex is "^([0-9A-Fa-f]+)\\ +([0-9A-Fa-f]+)\\ +([0-9]+)\\ +([0-9A-Fa-f]+)(\\ ([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))".
I can use a workaround to capture the last part and then make another regex for extract the bytes, but want to know if it's possible, not a workaround

Comment: @GabrielCiubotaru, You could use your full regex for a first pass: `^([\dA-F]+) +([\dA-F]+) +(\d+) +([\dA-F]+)(( [\dA-F]{2})+)`, then use the regex I gave in my answer to break down the ` 27 FB D9 59 50 56 6C 8A` that was captured in the last group. If this solves your problem, don't forget to mark it as the "accepted answer". Thanks!

Comment: This solve my first problem, but still, how can i make non capute grouping in haskell ? And btw, \d is not working in haskell.

Comment: @GabrielCiubotaru: I don't know if that's available in the library you're using, but you shouldn't need it to use my solution. On the first pass, just ignore the last match, which will contain the last byte.

Comment: @GabrielCiubotaru: I updated my answer to lay out all the steps.

Comment: This is exactly the workaround i made (but i use for second one split, no reason to use regex again).
Seems like noone know how to make non capturing group like this:^([\dA-F]+) +([\dA-F]+) +(\d+) +([\dA-F]+)((?: [\dA-F]{2})+).